# $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (nx^2)}{ 1 + n^3}$ is continuously differentiable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> **Problem.** Define, for $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
>   $$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (nx^2)}{1 + n^3}.$$
>   Then $f$ is a continuously diﬀerentiable function.

My try: $f$ will be uniformly convergent. If I can show $f'(x)$ = $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{2nx \cos (nx^2)}{1 + n^3}$, I will be done. But I have no clue how to proceed to prove that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: By a theorem from advanced calculus if $f=\sum f_n$ converges uniformly, each $f_n$ is continuously differentiable, and if $\sum f_n'$ also converges uniformly then $f$ is continuously differentiable (and $f'=\sum f_n'$). Here $\sum f_n'$ does not converge uniformly on the whole line, but it does converge uniformly on the interval $[-A,A]$ for every $A$; that's  enough.

Comment: As far as actually showing uniform convergence, consider the Weierstrass M-test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Isn't it sufficient to have point-wise convergence for $f = \sum f_n$. I'm looking at Theorem 5.18 in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch5.pdf. Is uniform convergence of $f_n \to f$ necessary for the $\textit{continuously}$ differentiable part?

Comment: You may want to have a look on [*this theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability). What is sufficient for your problem is to establish the locally uniform convergence of the termwise derivative, as in user284331's answer.

Comment: @AlkaKadri Yes. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my first solution messed up, since it is not the case that $|\sin z|\leq 1$ for any complex number $z$.

For the real case, actually @David C. Ullrich has answered completely. For the sequence $\{f_{n}\}$, $f_{n}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sin(nx^{2})}{1+n^{3}}$, $f_{n}$ is continuously differentiable with $f_{n}'(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2nx\cos(nx^{2})}{1+n^{3}}$. On each set $\{|x|\leq N\}$, Weierstrass test shows that $\{f_{n}'\}$ converges uniformly on $\{|x|\leq N\}$ and the limit function is continuous on this set. Now $N$ is an arbitrary positive integer, the limit function is continuous.

Comment: Thank you @Sangchul Lee for pointing out the crucial mistake, I didn't think carefully that about the boundedness for the complex sine function.